# Chrome cannot play videos on MSNBC news site

Tags: chrome-for-android, video

I am stuck on this issue. My Samsung Galaxy A7 Lite tablet (SM-T220) running Android version 13 and Chrome 111.0.5563.116 has a strange issue. Until a few weeks ago I had no issue playing MSNBC news videos. Click, unmute, and play without issue.

Cannot connect this issue with an upgrade, so this could be the issue but, one day suddenly a few weeks ago, MSNBC videos will not play when accessed through their website (https://www.msnbc.com/).

Any other website videos play as they did and should. Just MSNBC will not play. (No, I do not want to use the MSNBC app, sorry.)

Chrome Version 111.0.5563.110 (Official Build) (64-bit) on my laptop (Debian 11) still plays MSNBC videos. Chrome on my desktop (ArchLinux current) Chrome plays properly. (None of the installs have any extensions installed.)

I have tried various Pi Hole settings for my Samsung A7 client with no love.

I have tried what I think is everything. Any suggestions on what to try/test/adjust would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested if MSNBC videos work on a regular internet connection without Pi hole?

Comment: Both my laptop and desktop use Chrome and both can view MSNBC videos. My tablet, no video, only a black screen where the video should be playing. Enlarging to full screen makes no difference. The black screen continues. I think this fact may eliminate it being a PiHole issue.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem on my A7 Lite. So weird!

Comment: So, I tried on Pixel 3a, Android 12 and Samsung Galaxy M12, Android 13. On both devices, Chrome cannot play videos on MSNBC. Looks like there is an issue with the site because of how it loads the video chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to agree with Andrew T. post. Due to that post I checked my cellphone (Samsung 8? running Android 9 with Chrome 111.0.5563.116) and it will not play MSNBC videos either. So it leads me to believe that there has been an update to the MSNBC website that has broken video playback. However, on both devices, my tablet and my cellphone, MSNBC "Live TV" plays. This leaves me with one option (as I see it) to wait . . . patiently . . . I'm getting older, HURRY UP MSNBC, fix your code!!